# Preventing blurry text and images

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with blurry images on my site. I found a few solutions, but only

```
img{
   -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
   transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}
```

worked for me.

When I apply this css all images are shown nice, but the problem is that then all text becomes blurry.

Is there any way to avoid that?

Comment: Why are the images blurry in the first place?

Comment: @Santi I'm not sure. I use `transform: translateY(-50%)` in a few places. Maybe that's the reason.

Comment: you're going to have to show us an example.  Can you create a fiddle?

Comment: Check this link:-https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/i/image-rendering/

Answer (score 1):

In order to stop your images from being blurry; make sure they are of a high resolution, if you are using low res images they will display blurry on your webpage, also make sure you are not declaring a width and height that is causing them to be blurry. In order to display smoother/less blurry font in the browser try the following;

```
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; //webkit browsers
-moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale; //firefox/opera
text-rendering: optimizeLegibility; //all other browsers
```

Answer (score 1):

Try also using `transform: translateY(-51%)`